# Как запускать тесты по папкам или по тегам?

Tags: java, gradle, junit, test-automation

Пытаюсь запустить определённые тесты через консоль с помощью вот такой команды:

```
gradle test -PincludeTags="User_Service"
```

`UserService` - это `@Tag`.

Проблема в том, что он прогоняет все тесты, даже те, которые мне не нужно запускать.
Подскажите, что я не так делаю? Может что-то в `biuld.gradle` нужно добавить?

Comment: Надо смотреть  `build.gradle`. В командной строке запусти `gradle --help`, чтобы посмотреть какие аргументы можно использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтоб команда `gradle test -PincludeTags="User_Service"` запускала только тесты с указаным тегом нужно добавить в `build.gradle`:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        if (project.hasProperty("includeTags")) {
            includeTags(project.property("includeTags") as String)
        }
    }
}
```